# Changing color within navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying for change the color of the parameter "hover" within the navbar of the script.

In the css file "colors" I see this:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Changing "focus" works perfectly but If I try for change "hover" in this way, nothing:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a;
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

The other options are:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ababab;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: typo on line 1 - should be a comma instead of a semicolon

Comment: on the second version change the semicolon to a comma `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a;`<---comma.  When that's fixed it'll just do the same thing as the first version so kinda pointless.

Comment: Changed with comma but not change nothing.

Comment: Adult Video Script  ? 0.o

Comment: You want the color changed yet they are all the same `#e1e1e1` try `#baddad`

Comment: The background color of navbar is white. The "focus" parameter works well in grey. But also if I add #badcat on hover I see all white.

Comment: What does this have to do with videos?

Comment: Maybe remove all the `.active >` classes

Comment: @GDaquila `#badcat` is a typo. See my answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

There's an order to which you place these particular pseudo-selectors:

1. `a:link`
2. `a:visited`
3. `a:hover`
4. `a:active`
5. `a:focus`*

*`:focus` isn't in this series AFAIK, but put it last just in case.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:link,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  color: blue;
  font: 400 40px/1.5 Verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:active,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #b00b12;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<nav class='navbar-inverse'>
 <nav class='navbar-nav'>
  <div class='active'>
    <a href='#/https://pron.069'>Adult Videos</a>
  </div>
 </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: Adding a:active it works but... only on the current page. I'm in the Videos page and in the navbar the "hover" works but not in the other "buttons". Maybe because they are "inactive" ?

Comment: Most likely, any change of classes of the elements involved and everything will change. `.active` is an obvious suspect. The other"buttons" are more than likely not part of that ruleset. If you want all of your links(/buttons)? to behave the same, then use only `a` and remove the selectors that precede `a`

Comment: I tried for delete the selectors but not change nothing. It's strange because "focus" works well on all the buttons.

Comment: `focus` is generally a form associated event, when your last mouse or click is on a focusable element, it is usually highlighted until user unfocus (blur) by clicking elsewhere. Hover should work as well, and active is only working when you keep your finger on the mouse button.

Comment: Maybe hover is linked with other parameters in this case. I have added other navbar options in css file "colors".

Comment: @zer00ne, how did you get that color `#b00b12` ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst from GDaquila's site ^_^

Comment: I have find a solution: I have modified the color of text on hover and focus. In this way the text is always visible on the white background of navbar. Before instead with hover the text vanished because it was set white. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change ; in place of that use ,

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: Tried but nothing. It works with focus but "hover" not change.